# Call WCF service without wait callback

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I created a service using WCF to save log history of my system. My idea is that this service be called asynchronously, if the log service is offline the main system no need to wait for a return.

I added the parameter isOneWay in my method, as bellow:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
void Gravar(AuditoriaDTO objeto);
```

My service is very simple, just save the object in the database:

```
internal void Gravar(AuditoriaDTO objeto)
{
    try
    {
    StringBuilder strSql = new StringBuilder();

    strSql.Append("INSERT INTO ACECPGER_LOG.AUDITORIA");
    strSql.Append("       (COD_SISTEMA");
    strSql.Append("       ,COD_MODULO");
    strSql.Append("       ,COD_PROJETO");
    strSql.Append("       ,DSC_CLASSE");
    strSql.Append("       ,DSC_METODO");
    strSql.Append("       ,COD_RESULTADO");
    strSql.Append("       ,DSC_RESULTADO");
    strSql.Append("       ,DSC_STACKTRACE");
    strSql.Append("       ,DTH_INICIO");
    strSql.Append("       ,DTH_FIM");
    strSql.Append("       ,DSC_USUARIO)");
    strSql.Append(" VALUES");
    strSql.Append("       (:COD_SISTEMA");
    strSql.Append("       ,:COD_MODULO");
    strSql.Append("       ,:COD_PROJETO");
    strSql.Append("       ,:DSC_CLASSE");
    strSql.Append("       ,:DSC_METODO");
    strSql.Append("       ,:COD_RESULTADO");
    strSql.Append("       ,:DSC_RESULTADO");
    strSql.Append("       ,:DSC_STACKTRACE");
    strSql.Append("       ,:DTH_INICIO");
    strSql.Append("       ,:DTH_FIM");
    strSql.Append("       ,:DSC_USUARIO)");

    using (AcessoDadosOracle acessoDados = new AcessoDadosOracle())
    {
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":COD_SISTEMA", objeto.Sistema.Codigo);
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":COD_MODULO", objeto.Modulo.Codigo);
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":COD_PROJETO", objeto.Projeto.Codigo);
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":DSC_CLASSE", objeto.Classe);
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":DSC_METODO", objeto.Metodo);
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":COD_RESULTADO", objeto.CdResultado);
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":DSC_RESULTADO", objeto.Resultado);
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":DSC_STACKTRACE", objeto.StackTrace);
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":DTH_INICIO", objeto.DataInicio);
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":DTH_FIM", objeto.DataFim);
        acessoDados.AdicionarParametro(":DSC_USUARIO", objeto.Usuario);

        acessoDados.ExecuteNonQuery(strSql.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
}
```

In the call, I do the following:

```
using (AuditoriaService.AuditoriaClient servico = new AuditoriaService.AuditoriaClient())
{
    try
    {
        servico.GravarAsync(objeto);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         throw ex;
    }
}
```

During my testes, I added a breakpoint in the service, the application waits for a few seconds to continue with the other operations. I need the application not to wait even 1 second for the return of the service. Is this possible? How should you proceed?

My service reference is configured like this:

[image]

Comment: Apart from the catch clause, your client code seems fine. I guess your Service is blocking. But you didn't share the code.

Comment: After edit: Your service method is called "Gravar" but you are calling "GravarAsync" - is there a wrapper in between?

Comment: @Fildor, I edited my post and added what the service do. It's a very simple operation. If i stop the service, the application following, but wait arround 2 or 3 seconds when close "using".

Comment: In my service reference I check the option "Allow generation of asynchronous operations". When I do this, the system automatically generates all methods with the async extension as well

Comment: That doesn't mean they actually are _executed_ asynchronously, though.

Comment: If you choose the other option, Task based operations, you can call them without awaiting them and it will be "fire and forget". You must be careful though, depending on how your process works it could end before the call completes. A better option might be to drop the log message in a queue that is picked up by something that can make the call synchronously.

Comment: My service referente is configured as "generate task-based operations. In fact the system is not waiting, but there is slowness when the service is offline.

Comment: Do you think that i change GravarAsync by Gravar?